# How to get Original Facebook id instead of App scoped id by using Facebook SDK in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

Is there any way to get canonical Facebook id instead of App scoped id from facebook sdk. I have two version of app one in iOS and other in android. In iOS, FB SDK retrieves original user id while in Android SDK it fetches only app scoped id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, since the introduction of the Graph API v2.0, this is no longer possible, and it's by design:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api